# Is square of signal more recoverable than signal itself?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, sampling, continuous-signals, aliasing

Let $x[n]$ be aliased sampling of real-valued $x(t)$ over $t_0 \leq t \leq t_1$. Can $|x(t)|^2$ be recovered more accurately than $x(t)$, *over* $t_0 \leq t \leq t_1$? If so, how?

For $|x[n]|^2$, superficially it's "yes", as aliasing can circularly shift certain $X[k]$, which $|x[n]|$ is invariant to. For $|x(t)|^2$, I see potential as it's lower in information.

Feel free to assume the amount of aliasing to be "limited", by whatever amount necessary (but do specify it).

#### Clarifying

"Standard theory", meaning sinc interpolation, says "no", and that much is clear. All modulus is aliased, since it's many-to-one. Yet this same flaw is a strength in the general framework, as $|x|$ is lower-information, hence inherently takes less to recover. For example, [synchrosqueezed STFT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.2533.pdf) can beat sinc interpolation for non-uniform sampling.

For complex $x$ that's a bandpass signal, $|x|$ *can* often be recovered more accurately, as modulus heavily shifts energy toward lower frequencies, even if new higher ones are introduced. Different with real $x$, but case in point, I'd not conclude it can't be done just because sinc can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is square of signal more recoverable than signal itself?

Generally no. The spectrum of $x^2(t)$ is the convolution of $X(\omega)$ with itself.  This also means that if $x(t)$ has a bandwidth of B, $x^2(t)$ will have a bandwidth of 2B. It has twice the bandwidth so it's much more likely to create more aliasing.

Practical example: in audio processing, the signal is often up-sampled before doing non-linear processing (like squaring) to reduce the aliasing caused by the extended bandwidth.

Comment: Consider modulated BPSK (0 180 degree modulation) with no filtering. It has infinite BW with a Sinc shape but on a practical level the BW of the main lobe is twice the modulation rate. Interestingly when we square this, all modulation is stripped and we get a single tone at twice the carrier frequency and DC (in the original modulated signal the carrier was suppressed).   For typical filtered BPSK, the modulation is also suppressed, and 2x carrier recovered, but the doubled modulation will exist at a much lower level at twice the BW as you suggest.  Doubling QPSK produces a same BW BPSK sig.

Comment: ah, but that assumes symbol-synchronous sampling, @DanBoschen; that's not the same as being able to reconstruct an arbitrary signal from a sampled version :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller No I don't think so? We can arbitrarily sample the signal as long as we obey Nyquist (and oversampled enough to also include the 2x frequency, otherewise get an aliased version of that) and this effect will occur. Such carrier recovery using squaring can be done in the continuous time domain or at any sample rate prior to timing recovery. So basically bottom line for any modern modulation, squaring destroys any chance of recovering the signal.

Answer (score 0):

> Can |x(t)|² be recovered more accurately than x(t), over t0≤t≤t1? If so, how?

The situation for a sampling of $|x|^2$ can, *in the best case* only be *as most as good as for $x$*, unless frequency components in $x$ cancel upon squaring, which is a huge exception, and needs spectrum to be rationally related, and phases to be definite - that's such a significant restriction that I wouldn't call it a "continuous-time reconstruction from a sampled signal".

You can spectrally motivate that: squaring introduces intermodulation products of all the oscillations in $x$, thus adding *new* and *higher* frequencies to your aliasing.

> Yet this same flaw is a strength in the general framework, as |x| is lower-information,

It's exactly 1 bit lower in information – a sign information. But being continuous-valued, it has infinite information anyway, so this argument doesn't work.

Comment: Don't think it's worth staining an otherwise valid answer with the last paragraph's oversimplification. Sign is arguably half the information.

Comment: no, it's not half the information, it's literally 1 bit, assuming the signal is as likely to be positive as negative at any given time; $$\begin{align}I(\text{sign})  &= -P(\text{sign} = +) \cdot \log_2 [P(\text{sign} = +) ] -P(\text{sign} = -) \cdot  \log_2 [P(\text{sign} = -)]\\ &= - \frac 12 (-1)+ \frac12 (-1) \\&= \frac12 +\frac12 \\ &= 1.\end{align}$$ (any other distribution of signs has even less entropy in the sign.)

Comment: What if we encode ALL the information in the sign (such as BPSK)? Is that valid example to say there are cases where we could lose ALL the information?

Comment: @DanBoschen sure, but then we're not talking about the reconstruction of an arbitrary analog signal, but the reconstruction of the digital signal that last to that

Comment: @MarcusMüller Excellent point, which brings us back to just being 1 bit! And when you square QPSK which is 2 bits, you get BPSK, again losing 1 bit. Cool. Very insightful.

Comment: Sign is the subject of binary classifiers. Sign encodes a vast functional space of all possible aliases. Multiplicative deformations have miniscule impact on time-frequency ridges when they're unsigned compared to signed - plain sign flips can outdeform multiplication by absolute white noise. This can be confirmed in time, frequency, or time-frequency domains with Euclidean distance. Going from `float64` to `float16` loses much less than losing sign does, yet your metric likely suggests otherwise. I don't know your math, but I fear it strikes me as a variant of "lying with statistics". -1

Comment: Sorry, if you downvote because you don't understand the math – that's a bit sad, and it hints a bit at confirmation bias. Maybe instead ask about the math! You're question is about reconstructability, which is inherently a stochastic/statistical problem: there's an infinite amount of signals, and we need to describe which one of these happen how often, and how much these are "reconstructable" so that we can say something about reconstruction over the whole class of signals. We can describe the *distortion* that happens in reconstruction in the mathematical sense.

Comment: To describe the amount of information lost through that, we consider the amount of Shannon Information in a signal; information is additive for *statistically independent* aspects of a signal (for example, the information in a complex Gaussian random variable is the sum of the information in its angle, and the information in its magnitude, as these are independent) and that's why I calculated for the sign you lose; nothing about this is "lying with statistics".

Comment: If the math says the sun is a pebble then it's being misused, and isn't worth someone's time. If the difference between $x$ and $|x|$ is as trivial as "1 bit", I invite you to recover former from latter within 1 bit. Also @-less notifs don't work with >1 replier.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon um, but this math describes your signal's properties, so it does apply… What it doesn't do is confirm your suspicion.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon also, if you give me the value of $|x|$ and 1 bit in sign information, yes, I can recover $x$; you're kind of making my point there!

Comment: What's "1 bit"? How many bits is $x$? Can you store `[1, -1, 1, -1, ...]` as a single `0` & `1`?

Comment: no, but if you remove the sign from every one of these numbers, you lose exactly 1 bit each time; that's the point I was making above :) Now, for your real-valued signal, each of these values still contain uncountably much information after removal of the sign. That's why removing the sign does not lead to a signal with much less information. *Almost all* (in the math sense of that phrase) information is still there and needs to be reconstructed.